# Which is the best method or algorithm to compare two large lists of email addresses?

Tags: algorithm, hadoop

Which is the best method or algorithm to compare two large lists of email addresses in a short time?

The idea is to detect as many addresses in list can be found in list B.

The lists are not equal.
I tried fuzzy checksum, but it would be good only if the lists are of equal size (in my case lists are not equal).

I think a Hadoop solution, but unfortunately I am a beginner in Hadoop. Does anyone have any ideas, examples, solutions, tutorials ?

Thanks

Comment: How large of a list are we talking about?  Larger than main memory?  Larger than whose hashes can be stored in main memory?  Larger than disk?

Comment: Lists can have several million addresses. They will not be larger than can be stored in main memomoria

Comment: That's actually not that big.  Are the lists ordered?

Comment: What do you want the output to be? The difference? The equality?

Comment: lists are not ordered (but a first step would be to order them), and the result will be what addresses are identical (equal), or percentage, what percentage of the list A is found in the list B

Answer (score 3):

If you regard to each list as a set, the common addresses are represented by the set [**intersection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29). The 'unique' addresses (appear in one only) is denoted by:

```
set1 U set2 \ (set1 [intersection] set2)
```

It can be done easily in all high level languages such as java, have a look on apache [`CollectionUtils.intersection()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#intersection%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29) for example.

If the lists are not too huge (fit memory), it can be done in memory as follows (java code):

```
    //first two lines are just for testing, not part of the algorithm:
    List<String> l1 = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "a@b.com", "1@2.com"} );
    List<String> l2 = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "1@2.com", "asd@f.com", "qwer@ty.com"} );
    Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<String>(l1);
    for (String s : l2) {
        if (s1.contains(s)) System.out.println(s);
    }
```

If you want to use **hadoop**, the common mails can be achieved with:

```
map(set):
   for each mail in list:
         emit(mail,'1')
reduce(mail,list<1>):
    if size(list) > 1:
       emit(mail)
```

by invoking map on both sets, and reduce on the output of the mapper, you will get the common elements.

Comment: Thanks, I'll will try both solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do the job for you?  Should be O(n).

```
Create an empty hash set for the intersection with a hash function that doesn't collide over email addresses
Create an empty hash set for the first difference hash set with a similar hash function
Create an empty hash set for the second difference hash set with a similar hash function
Iterate through the first list:
    Add the current element to the first difference hash set
End Iterate
Iterate through the second list:
    If the current element exists in the intersection hash set:
        Remove the current element from the first difference hash set
        Remove the current element from the second difference hash set
    Else If the current element exists in the first difference hash set:
        Remove the current element from the first difference hash set
        Remove the current element from the second difference hash set
        Add the current element to the intersection hash set
    Else:
        Add the current element to the second difference hash set
    End If
End Iterate
Process the intersection hash set as the solution
```

It has the benefit of giving you both the intersection and the difference.  It can be extended to track the difference between any number of lists.

Comment: I altered the logic a bit, because I spotted a problem.